Getting a feel of how slow-growing iterated logarithm truly is
Let $F$ be a set of functions such that

$\log n \in F$
for every $f(n) \in F$ we have $\log (f(n)) \in F$
$F$ is minimal

Simply put, $F = \{ \log n, \log (\log n), \log(\log(\log n)), \ldots \}$
Is it true that $\log^* n = \mathcal{O}(f)$ for every $f \in F$ ? i.e. the iterated logarithm is slower-growing than any function that is a composition of an arbitrary number logarithms (but still divergent)?

Yes, that's true, and it shouldn't be too hard to prove. Let $f \in F$, then $f$ is on the form $f = \log^t$ for some $t > 0$.
Let $n_0 = t$ and $c = 1$. Continue the proof from here.
